Android Studio: Room live updates not automatically refreshing
Unable to provide specific code as it is an internal business application. Running Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 with Room DB inspector with Live updates enabled. Inserts and deletes are not automatically updated in the UI. Rerunning the query shows the entity changes. Has anyone seen this and solved it? I have tried to invalidate/restart and detach/reattach the tablet.
